# how could I convert boost::this_thread::get_id() to int?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

```
void Test  
{  
    boost::thread::id id0 = boost::this_thread::get_id();  
    int iThreadId = id0; // ***here, how could I cast 'id0' to 'iThreadId'***  
}
```

Could someone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, you can't cast from _object_ to _object_. You cast a _value_ to _another type_.

Comment: Although this thread is fairly old, I'm still gonna answer for those who will need it for some reason.
You can convert boost::thread::id to int using boost::lexical_cast<int>(thread_id);

Answer (score 1):

`std::hash<>` is specialized for `std::hash<std::thread::id`

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/hash

Likely, `boost::thread::id` has the same.

So you could use

```
 std::hash<boost::thread::id>(thread_id);
```

to get an integral representation. Of course, (sadly) since this is supposed to be used as a hash, there might not be a guarantee that the resulting hashes are unique for each thread. You will still do good to look up the documentation for your (version of the) library.

However, just for use as e.g. key in an `unordered_map`, you'd not have to worry about it.

**Alternatively** if you want this to be 'API compatible' with your pre-c++11 threading solution **and** you don't mind using implementation-dependent features, you could use **[`std::thread::native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle)**. This is more than likely to have the same type that your 'old' threading API exposed. (`std::thread::native_handle_type` is implementation defined)